# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I imported one spring hibernate maven example in eclipse. There isn't any error, but after running the project, it shows **HTTP 404 error** on screen and on console I get:

```
Jul 15, 2014 6:10:17 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/bookstore/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Please tell me why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING says it all :  you don't have any mapping defined for this URI. Please define a mapping (SimpleUrlHandlerMapping for example) which will map this URI to a controller.Of course you also need to define the controller as well.And make sure you have proper url pattern defined for DispatcherServlet.